scalatest matchPattern causes an unmatchable warning in Scala 3
I am using Scala 3.4.1 and scalatest 3.2.18. The example code from the documentation is:
case class Name(first: String, middle: String, last: String)

val name = Name("Jane", "Q", "Programmer")

name should matchPattern { case Name("Sarah", _, _) => }

This results in the following warning:
Pattern selector should be an instance of Matchable,, 
but it has unmatchable type Any instead
    name should matchPattern { case Name("Sarah", _, _) => }

Since I am using -Xfatal-warnings this results in a compiler error. I know I can fix it by using inside instead, but that is uglier and the error message (in case of a failed assertion) is not as nice.
Is there a way to tell the compiler that this is a legitimate pattern matching and be able to use matchPattern?
